Is it possible to replace the `sidebyside` "wheel" of the package `tcolorbox`?
As the question described, I use the sidebyside "wheel" of the tcolorbox package to create an environment for achieve "left: text and right: figure". Is it possible to create this "wheel" without loading the tcolorbox package? What's more, I don't want to use the minipage or paracol environment, because for the former I need to type \noindent manually and for the latter, I need to type \vfill twice to center the figure on the right vertically.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm,tcolorbox}
\NewTColorBox { textfig } { O { .64\linewidth } }
  {
    sidebyside, sidebyside gap = .02\linewidth, boxsep = 0pt,
    left = 0pt, right = 0pt, top = 3pt, bottom = 0pt,
    lefthand width = #1, standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, frame empty
  }
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{textfig}
  \begin{problem}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{problem}
  \tcblower
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{textfig}

\end{document}


why not just define a custom environment which adds \noindent or \vfill or whatever?

You can, of course, always create your own, but it is hard to know how somebody else wants such a thing configured without knowing what that person objects to in the sidebyside implementation, for example, so this is proof-of-concept. Tweaks are left as an exercise for the reader.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm,tcolorbox}
\NewTColorBox { textfig } { O { .64\linewidth } }
{
  sidebyside, sidebyside gap = .02\linewidth, boxsep = 0pt,
  left = 0pt, right = 0pt, top = 3pt, bottom = 0pt,
  lefthand width = #1, standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, frame empty
}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{twinned}{ O {.64\linewidth} m +b }
{%
  \medskip
  \par
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{#1}
    \noindent
    #3
  \end{minipage}%
  \hskip 0.02\linewidth
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.98\linewidth-#1}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{#2}
  \end{minipage}%
}{%
  \medskip
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{textfig}
  \begin{problem}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{problem}
  \tcblower
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{textfig}

\begin{twinned}{cow}
  \begin{problem}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{problem}
\end{twinned}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}


If twinned does everything you need, you can, obviously, dispense with tcolorbox and just load graphicx. If it cannot easily be customised to do what you need, you need to be more specific about what that is.
It gets more complicated if you want the dashed line, obviously. (Personally, I would omit it on aesthetic grounds, but you may prefer it.)
